# Работа со строками в С : Access violation

Tags: c, строки

**Код:**

Вызов функции:

```
char* converted = ConvertDoubleToStr(666654);
printf("Converted string: %s \n", converted);
```

Функция:

```
char* ConvertDoubleToStr(double d)
{
    const int t = sizeof (double);
    char resultT[t] = " ";

    //int const dLength = sprintf(resultT, 0, "%lf", d);
    int const dLength = sprintf(resultT, "%lf", d);
    if (dLength < 0)
        return NULL;

    char *result = (char*)malloc(dLength + 1);
    if (result == NULL)
        return NULL;

    //int const resultLength = sprintf(result, dLength + 1, "%lf", d);
    int const resultLength = sprintf(result, "%lf", d);
    if (resultLength < 0) {
        free(result);
        return NULL;
    }

    printf("Converted string (d->s): %s \n", result);
    return result;
}
```

При выходе из функции (к стати, строка `printf("Converted string (d->s): %s \n", result);` показывает правильно результат) при присваивании результата функции 
я получаю ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я не прав?**
Спасибо

Comment: @Эникейщик не подходит, и return (char*)result тоже

Comment: Что за ерунда здесь творится? `int const dLength = sprintf(resultT, "%lf", d);`? Пишете в 8 байт строку куда большего размера...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`666654.000000` - это то, что Вы написали в `resultT`, размер которого `8` (из каких соображений? потому что `double` - восьмибайтный?). Стек - вдребезги.

---

```
int t = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%lf", d);
char resultT[t + 1];
sprintf(resultT, "%lf", d);
```

Comment: Да, Вы правы, проблема в длине массива. А как в моем случае можно узнать требуемый размер массива result перед вызово функции "sprintf" чтобы наполнить его ?

Comment: @LeonidZolotarov Вам же уже рассказывали про функцию `snprintf`.

Comment: Я  'snprintf' не могу использовать, т.к. она для С++, а я на  С пишу. При добавлении заголовочного файла, я все равно не смог ее использовать

Comment: @LeonidZolotarov Ну напишите `char resultT[100];`.

Comment: @LeonidZolotarov `snprintf` вполне себе функция из C, точнее из C99